# XmlDocument.SelectNodes and XPath Navigation

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, selectnodes

I have XML code that looks similar to this:

```
  <BookStore xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Book>
    <bookGenre>Fantasy</bookGenre>
    <bookTitle>A Storm of Swords</bookTitle>
    <authorInformation>
      <authorId>12345</authorId>
      <authorName>
        <firstName>George</firstName>
        <middleInitial>R.R.</middleInitial>
        <lastName>Martin</lastName>
      </authorName>
    </authorInformation>
  </Book>
  <customer>
    <customerData />
  </customer>
</BookStore>
```

The `<customer>`node may or may not have child nodes, depending on user input.

I am trying to use XmlDocument.SelectNodes and XPath navigation to select `<BookStore>`, `<customer>`, and any nodes contained within `<customer>`.

I have been looking around and reading about XPath and .SelectNodes for a few hours but still don't seem to fully understand how they work. Would anyone have an explanation as to how to use them or how I could use them in my situation? If there are other ways to go about solving my problem I'm open to those too! (I am using C#)

**EDIT:** here's what I tried based on the stuff I read

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xmlStr);
XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;

XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
nsmgr.AddNamespace("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");

XmlNodeList nodeList = root.SelectNodes("descendant::customer:child::Node");

doc.Save(Console.Out);
```

Comment: Please show us what you tried.

Comment: Added code that I tried.

Comment: So what happens when you call `doc.LoadXml()` and give it a filename instead of an XML string? I know what happens. I'm asking you why you didn't say anything in your question about getting an exception when you try to parse the XML.

Comment: With LINQ to XML it should be `var customerData = XDocument.Load(fileName).Descendants("customerData");`

Comment: Oh sorry that's really confusing on my part, I used to be using a file but later I just changed fileName to be taking in an XML string without changing the variable name, I'll edit that :P

Answer (score 1):

Try xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication62
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            XElement customer = doc.Descendants("customer").FirstOrDefault();

            Boolean children = customer.HasElements;

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do something like this using an XML string as input instead of a file?

Comment: Definitely.  Use XDocument.Parse(string) instead of xDocument.Load(filename or uri).